# how to build user defined laser scan message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have seen default laser scan message which is something like that sensormsg::LaserScan. what i want is to make my own laser scan message identical to the default one. also i want to fill that laserscan message with my dumy data.

hope someone can help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55858/how-to-build-user-defined-laser-scan-message/) by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-21**:
Why would you want to do that? It seems like a bad idea to make an identical message.

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-02-21**:
i,m doing this for global mapping. want to run two gmaping algo, one for robot laser scan and second for the laser scan through wifi from other robot. is there any other approach? . i hve alrdy written code of local maps alignment and merging to form a global map, jst figring out how to locliz them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want two algorithms using lasers, there is no need to define a custom message. Instead use [topic remapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) to map laser scans from one source to one algorithm and laser scans from another source to the other algorithm.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-02-21**:
can i do this with gmapping algorithms. how will i differentiate between the between laser scans running parallel. and how to fill laser scan with dummy scan?. i am new in ROS.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-21**:
The laser scans will have different topic names. If you don't know what that means, you should follow the basic tutorials and introduction. Why would you want to fill a dummy scan?

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-02-21**:
yes rxgraph help me to understane ,also i have gone through tutorials. actually i,m doing this for global mapping and localization . dummy scan will be the laser scan coming from other robot through wifi. is this rite ? or i must adpt any other approach for global SLAM(two robots).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-21**:
Well, with this approach you'll get two independent maps. Global localization can't be achieved by just ROS topic modification, you need an actual specific algorithm for that.

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-02-21**:
is there algorithm you know or should should i rite my own code for it. thanks